# Extract grep match with sed

Tags: unix, sed, grep

I'm trying to run the following:

```
echo $line | grep "u01/app/[0-9]" | sed -n 's/[0-9]|\./p'
```

Where

```
line="orb 14171 orb 3u REG 253,3 0 14141 /u01/app/11.2.0.4/broa/log/stm1025/agent/"
```

And what I would like to do is extract the version number, and store it in a variable, but whenever I run the above command, all I seem to get it sed: command garbled: `s/[0-9]p`

Anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: What is the value you like as output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `awk`

```
ver=$(awk -F/ '/u01\/app\/[0-9]/ {print $4}' <<< "$line")
echo "$ver"
11.2.0.4
```

It takes the fourth field from the variable `line` and store it to a variable `ver`

If its only one line in the variable, you can skip the test and use:

```
ver=$(awk -F/ '{print $4}' <<< "$line")
```

Simple to understand, and just give the value directly. No complicated regex :)

Comment: It does not change anything thanks to `-F` that marks `/` as the field separator

Comment: Amazing! So does it start from the "/u01\/app\/[0-9]/" part?

Comment: no, `$1` will be `orb 14171 orb 3u REG 253,3 0 14141 ` (before the first separator) -- the `/u01\/app\/[0-9]/` part is just the pattern to match, it is not anchored to the start of line

Comment: @AkshaiShah No, it divides the file separated by `/`. So the fourth field is still `11.2.0.4`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have bash and GNU grep:

```
version=$(grep -oP '(?<=/u01/app/).+?(?=/)' <<< "$line")
echo "$version"    # => 11.2.0.4
```

That PCRE regex finds all characters between `/u01/app/` and the next `/`

Answer (score 2):

when I run your sed command, my sed is telling:

```
sed -n 's/[0-9]|\./p'
sed: 1: "s/[0-9]|\./p": unterminated substitute in regular expression
```

which is because you did not make a full substitution command, the substitution command has the following syntax : `s/…/…/` whereas you only made it `s/…/`.

you can try, to stick with sed:

```
echo $line | sed -e 's,.*/u01/app/\([0-9\.]*\)*/.*,\1,'
11.2.0.4
```

Comment: `[0-9.]` should be enough, no escape dot needed in class. the `+` is maybe better for the version extraction instead of `*`. An alternative is `[^/]\{1,\}`